# How to add onSelect & onDeselect events Kendo multi-select AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, events, kendo-ui, multi-select, kendo-multiselect

I am using [Kendo multi-select](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index) to implement a tag based filter widget. I am using Angular as my framework.

I have stucked in adding onSelect and onDeSelect events to be triggered when the user select, deselect a tag. I could only found [this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/events) example. But I can't find a way how I can do it with Angular.

Can some one please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a function for `onSelect()` and specify it as the onSelect method in HTML by

```
<select kendo-multi-select
                    k-data-source="vm.filterGroup.groupItems"
                    k-select="vm.onSelect"</select>
```

workd for me.

Answer (score 1):

What about putting the handlers in the options object like this:

http://dojo.telerik.com/oDanU

Comment: what is this k-options="selectOptions" do?

Comment: sets the options of the widget